# Cannot boot into fastbootd OnePlus 8T

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, bootloader, reboot, oneplus

I'm trying to manually flash the factory image on my OnePlus 8T ([using this TCD guide](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/oneplus-factory-image-creation-guide/)).

I was able to boot my phone into Fastboot mode using the volume + power keys. I'm able to execute `fastboot devices` and successfully flashed all images in Section 8 of the above mentioned tutorial before it gets to the `fastboot reboot fastboot` command (i.e. boot.img, dtbo.img, etc.)

When I try to execute `fastboot reboot fastboot`, I get the following error: `fastboot: usage: unknown reboot target fastboot`.

It seems other people have this problem as well and it's due to some changes that happened in Android 10 (my OnePlus 8T is on Android 11). Reading [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fastboot-flash-system-partition-not-found.3992977/), comments #14 - #18 (inclusive) I think describe the underlying problem, but I don't understand the solution.

Do I need to execute a different command, is there a process I need to complete first?

For broader context, I was rooting my phone and got into a bootloop. Fastboot can recognize my phone but not adb. I'm trying to get a clean start by restoring it to the factory image and have successfully completed all the steps in [the TCD guide](https://www.thecustomdroid.com/oneplus-factory-image-creation-guide/) except for the final step of flashing the images.

Here's a screenshot of my terminal -

[image]

My adb version is:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 0.0.1-4500957
Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
```

Updates:

- I tried `fastboot reboot bootloader` which does successfully reboot into bootloader, but then I cannot flash the other images. When I try, I get the error: `FAILED (remote: Flashing is not allowed for Critical Partitions)` which I think is because I'm not in "fastbootd" which seems to be important based on [the XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fastboot-flash-system-partition-not-found.3992977/)
- When I try `fastboot reboot recovery`, I am not booted into recovery but get the same error: `fastboot: usage: unknown reboot target recovery`
- I ran `fastboot boot imagefv.img` and got the following. My phone is now showing a screen with the OnePlus logo and the words "Fastboot Mode", but no other options.

[image]

- I was able to enter recovery mode from the fastboot screen and from recovery reboot to fastboot, but still unable to enter fastbootd. [This guide suggested I could enter fastbootd from recovery, but was unable.](https://www.getdroidtips.com/what-is-fastbootd-how-to-enable-and-boot/)

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded Android's SDK Platform-Tools, extracted the platform-tools folder and ran a terminal in side that directory. When I executed `./fastboot reboot fastboot` it did boot into `fastbootd` successfully. What's weird is that I installed platform-tools, put it in my /etc/ folder, and added it to my PATHS only 2 days ago. I'm not sure why exactly this worked...